# How to Get the arrow to "top header" without changing XML content of "Top header"

Tags: java, android, css, xml

[image]

Hi friends, I'm new to Andriod, I need to get the forward arrow to top of the header.

also i'm using top_header_layout.xml in many activity,

so without changing XML content of top_header_layout, I need to get forward arrow to top header is it possible?? help me.

thanks in advance. :)

Comment: It is not called "Top Header" but called "app-bar" aka "Action-Bar" !!

Comment: show the code that draws the elements.

Answer (score 1):

I hope I understood your question correctly:

You want to get that "right" Arrow into the ToolBar (like the "left" arrow on the left side).

Typically the [Android Menu](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/menus.html) is placed there.

So you should add a menu with the according icon instead of putting it into your Activity layout.

Example:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:id="@+id/forward"
          android:icon="@drawable/ic_arrow_right"
          android:title="@string/forward"
          android:showAsAction="always"/>
</menu>
```

Replace the icon with your icon.

Comment: You understood well, I want get that right arrow into the tool bar But I used same XML file in many  activity so if change this xml code it will affect all other activity. so i need help without changing Xml.

Comment: Any other way than putting it into the menu seems hacky and should not be done in my opinion.

Answer (score 0):

First, you need to create one menu-file (let's say `menu_forward.xml`) in your res/menu folder.

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto" >
    <item
        android:id="@+id/menu_forward"
        android:icon="@drawable/forward_button"
        android:title="Next"
        app:showAsAction="ifRoom" />
</menu>
```

Then override following two Methods in your `Activity`.

```
@Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_forward, menu);
        return true;
    }

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

    if (item.getItemId() == android.R.id.menu_forward) {
        // Do whatever when user press that button
    }
}
```